# Round up to nickel, dime, quarters

Tags: math, rounding

Here is what I have to do:

Write a program that makes change for amounts less than one dollar. Input to the program must be a positive integer less than 100, representing an amount of money, in cents. Output must be the original amount of money together with a set of coins (quarters, dimes, nickels) that could make up the amount. The program must produce change containing the minimum number of coins required to produce the given amount. **Should not include any pennies.** For example, the input of 54 should produce results such as:

54 cents requires 2 quarters, 1 nickel

rather than

54 cents requires 2 quarters, 0 dimes, 1 nickels

The following is what i have done so far but doesn't round up if I enter 13,14,23,24,33,34,ect.

Any help would be much appreciated.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class MakeChangetest {

    public static String makeChange(int change) throws BadChangeException {
        int amount;
        String x = "";
        if (change > 0 && change < 100) {
            amount = (int) ((Math.round(change / 5)) * 5);
            if (amount == 0 || amount == 100) {
                x = "No change to be given.";
            }
            if (amount == 5) {
                x = change + " cents requires " + " 1 nickel ";
            } else if (amount == 10 || amount == 20) {
                x = change + " cents requires " + (amount / 10) + " dimes ";
            } else if (amount == 15) {
                x = change + " cents requires " + (amount / 10) + " dime, "
                        + " 1 nickel ";
            } else if (amount == 25 || amount == 50 || amount == 75) {
                x = change + " cents requires " + (amount / 25) + " quaters ";
            } else if (amount == 30 || amount == 55 || amount == 80) {
                x = change + " cents requires " + (amount / 25) + " quaters, "
                        + " 1 nickel";
            } else if (amount == 35 || amount == 60 || amount == 70 || amount == 45 || amount == 85
                    || amount == 95) {
                if (amount % 25 == 10) {
                    x = change + " cents requires " + (amount / 25) + " quater, "
                            + "1 dime ";
                } else
                    x = change + "cents requires " + (amount / 25) + " quaters, "
                            + " 2 dimes ";
            } else if (amount == 40 || amount == 65 || amount == 90) {
                if (amount / 25 == 15) {
                    x = change + " cents requires " + (amount / 25) + " quater, "
                            + " 1 dime, " + " 1 nickel ";
                } else
                    x = change + " cents requires " + (amount / 25) + " quaters, "
                            + " 1 dime, " + " 1 nickel ";
            }
        } else
            throw new BadChangeException(
                    "Amount is not in the range to be given change for.");
        return x;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws BadChangeException {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter an amount to calculate the amount of change to be given:");
        double t = input.nextDouble();
        try {
            System.out.println(makeChange((int) t));
        } catch (BadChangeException ex) {
            System.out.print("Amount is not in the range to be given change for.");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You got so many if statements, use a switch instead. I'll update this answer in a sec with a bit cleaned up code.

Here's some cleaned up code with the included fix from the other answer:

```
public class MakeChangetest {

    public static String makeChange(int change) throws BadChangeException {
        int amount;
        String x = "";
        if (0 <= change <= 100) {
            amount = (int) ((Math.round(change / 5.0)) * 5);
            switch(amount) {
                case 0:
                case 100:
                    x = "No change to be given.";
                    break;
                case 5:
                    x = change + " cents requires " + " 1 nickel ";
                    break;
                case 10:
                case 20:
                    x = change + " cents requires " + (amount / 10) + " dimes ";
                    break;
                case 15:
                    x = change + " cents requires " + (amount / 10) + " dime, " + " 1 nickel ";
                    break;
                case 25:
                case 50:
                case 75:
                    x = change + " cents requires " + (amount / 25) + " quaters ";
                    break;
                case 30:
                case 55:
                case 80:
                    x = change + " cents requires " + (amount / 25) + " quaters, " + " 1 nickel";
                    brea;
                case 35:
                case 60:
                case 70:
                case 45:
                case 85:
                case 95:
                    if (amount % 25 == 10) {
                        x = change + " cents requires " + (amount / 25) + " quater, " + "1 dime ";
                    } else {
                        x = change + "cents requires " + (amount / 25) + " quaters, " + " 2 dimes ";
                    }
                    break;
                case 40:
                case 65:
                case 90:
                    if (amount / 25 == 15) {
                        x = change + " cents requires " + (amount / 25) + " quater, " + " 1 dime, " + " 1 nickel ";
                    } else {
                        x = change + " cents requires " + (amount / 25) + " quaters, " + " 1 dime, " + " 1 nickel ";
                    }
            }
        } else
            throw new BadChangeException(
                    "Amount is not in the range to be given change for.");
        return x;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws BadChangeException {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter an amount to calculate the amount of change to be given:");
        double t = input.nextDouble();
        try {
            System.out.println(makeChange((int) t));
        } catch (BadChangeException ex) {
            System.out.print("Amount is not in the range to be given change for.");
        }
    }
}
```

So always try to stay away from nesting multiple if else statements, things get messy and hard to read fast.

Also you can write `(0 < change && change < 100)` as `(0 < change < 100)`.
And the code wouldn't work properly since `(0 < change < 100)` does not include `0` and `100` but you actually need to include those since you're checking for `0` and `100` in the code below.

So instead it should be `(0 <= change <= 100)`.

Answer (score 1):

When you write `change / 5` both `change` and `5` are integers, and so Java preforms integer division. Integer division rounds down, so for example:

```
(Math.round(14 / 5)) * 5 =>  (Math.round(2)) * 5 => 10
```

To solve this you need one of the operands to be a floating point number:

```
amount = (int) ((Math.round(change / 5.0)) * 5);
```

or

```
amount = (int) ((Math.round(change / 5.0f)) * 5);
```

or

```
amount = (int) ((Math.round((float)change / 5)) * 5);
```

Comment: Didn't know that integer division rounds down, learned something new today, thanks!

Comment: More formally, it disregards the remainder rather then rounding down, which amounts to the same thing...